# Make IIS7.5 use custom error page

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, custom-error-pages

I have a custom error page. It works on my production server, but not on my dev machine. It's Windows 7, IIS 7.5.

I cannot get it to actually execute my custom page, although I can get it to respect detailed-local vs custom always. It just doesn't actually hand over to my custom error page and instead gives me the generic "Runtime Error" page for the remote mode.

Facts that might be relevant: it's an application mounted under a different app pool and web.config, this one is .NET 4.0, Integrated.

I was able to get it working, once, with "Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;" - but it did a redirect instead of an execute so I lost the error context which of course is the whole point - and in trying to change the redirect mode I was unable to get it to work again.

I've tried using both customErrors and httpErrors in all the documented/standard ways, but no combination works. Again, I have had this working correctly elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The above is a normal response - if your error page is itself generating an exception.

It turned out the same code causing the original error was in the execution of the error page.